# SELECT TOP 20 Percent SQL

Tags: sql

I have a query which can select TOP 20 percent of TOP highest with `GrandTotal`. But there is something is not fair. For example, in between the Top 20 out of 10 People is 2. So the out put is show this:

```
EmpName   GrandTotal
Kelvin      50
Gem         40
```

But the grand total of the 3rd and 4th people also having 40 as Grand Total. I need some idea and advice, how i going to do solve this problem?

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT 
    EmpName,
    SUM(Scoring) AS GrandTotal 
FROM  
    [masterView] 
GROUP BY
    EmpName 
ORDER BY 
    GrandTotal DESC, EmpName ASC
```

Comment: tag the database being used

Comment: Does you database support `rank`?

Comment: You could use your query to find to lowest grandTotal and then just select everything >= that.

Answer (score 1):

On SQL server you can use `WITH TIES` in order to include ties

```
SELECT TOP 20 PERCENT WITH TIES Id, sum(Score) as GrandTotal
FROM myTable GROUP BY Id 
ORDER BY GrandTotal DESC
```

Comment: the Id = employee ID?

Comment: Thank you. you just solved my problem. which mean WITH TIES will give me fair result. Thanks again.

Comment: remember accept this answer as correct if that solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d9cc2/15)**

**Test Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([ID] int, [Score] int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([ID], [Score])
VALUES
    (1, 10),        (2, 20),
    (3, 30),        (4, 20),
    (5, 10),        (6, 40),
    (7, 40),        (8, 50),
    (9, 10),        (10, 5);
```

**Query**

```
with ranked as (
    select 
         id, 
         rank() over (order by Score desc) as rnk
    from Table1
),
total as (
    select count(*) as total
    from Table1
)
SELECT *
FROM ranked
CROSS JOIN total
WHERE ranked.rnk <= 0.2 * total.total
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | rnk | total |
|----|-----|-------|
|  8 |   1 |    10 |
|  6 |   2 |    10 |
|  7 |   2 |    10 |
```